# Sticky navigation JS on picture not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation, sticky

I want to have a sticky navigation on my page. Right now it doesn't work (have a look at the jsfiddle). Tried already different things to make it work. Tried also different solutions from different websites but nothing seems to work. Can you help me?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Titel</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
      <header class="parallax">
          <nav class="header-navigation">
              <div class="header-navigation-child">
                  <div class="logo">Logo</div>
                  <div class="navigation">Hello World</div>
              </div>
          </nav>
      </header>
      <main>
        <article>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   

                Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.   

                Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.   

                Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.   

                Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis.   

                At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, At accusam aliquyam diam diam dolore dolores duo eirmod eos erat, et nonumy sed tempor et et invidunt justo labore Stet clita ea et gubergren, kasd magna no rebum. sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua. est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
            </p>
        </article>
      </main>
      <footer>
          <nav></nav>
      </footer>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body, html {
    font: 16px Arial, sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.parallax {
    background-image: url("img/parallax.jpg");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
}

.header-navigation {
    height: 60px;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.header-navigation-child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30%;
    margin: auto;
}

.logo {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 75px;
}

.navigation {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 50px;
}

.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

JS

```
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var navbar = document.getElementById("header-navigation");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n1m9j62v/3/

Any ideas?

Comment: The js code is from this site https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_sticky.asp

Comment: .sticky {
    position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
} did it for me

Comment: There's no #header-navigation, since you're targeting it with JS, among other things.